How do you Combine Multiple Transformations into one Transformation Matrix with Geometry Nodes?
Stupid Question here,
I want to combine multiple transformations into one total transformation.
In my example, I have two Object Info nodes whose transformations, I want to apply to some random mesh (Icosphere).

I figured out how to combine Positions and Scales but not Rotations. Or perhaps there is an easier way with the new Matrix Attribute?

Both for Rotation and for Transformation you can use Multiplication nodes.

Perhaps, I can answer this question myself for those that are still interested.
In short, you can’t. At least, not easily though.
Let’s first examine what the goal is. You want to combine multiple separate transformations/transformation matrices into one total or compound transformation matrix. The word, combine, isn’t very descriptive for our context (I would have elaborated if asked) but, from the image that was posted, we can deduce that it is an operation that “looks” binary and thus possibly abelian. In other words, you want a compound transformation matrix whose individual transformations can be reordered and canceled out when combining inverses as well.

As you have noticed, multiple translations and multiple scales can be combined into single compound translations and single compound scales respectively. However, Rotations cannot be combined in the same way. That’s because for rotations, ORDER MATTERS. This is true whether you’re using quaternions or euler rotations. This result is not just a technicality of Blender but a mathematical one as well. Thus, there is likely no property of matrices that can resolve this combination issue (this is just an opinion and isn’t something I’ve worked out). So, when combining, you won’t get a single compound transformation matrix but at least 2 different, unique combinations when 2 or more transformations are combined.

If you combine without order then this is impossible to achieve but, if you do combine with order in mind, you can achieve combining with the Rotate Rotation node.

Likewise, only the rotation ordered last can be canceled out with its inverse.

From a mathematical point of view, because a matrix coding a rotation is not symetric, the product of two rotation matrices is not commutative. This means that changing the order is changing the result $A \times B \neq B \times A$. To inverse $A \times B$, apply $B^{-1} \times A^{-1}$.
